# How to Stop Postman Newman From Consuming JavaScript Memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, postman, newman

How can I stop newman from consuming a lot of JavaScript heap memory.And is there any way to delete the things being put in the memory after each request completes.

I have a number of requests that need to repeat themselves for more than 3000+ times to get all the responses needed. So I need to prevent memory leaking.

So how can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide more details on whether you are using any local or global variables in your tests? If yes, it would be good to clear after each request